# VB6: enabling mousewheel for controls

Tags: vb6, mousewheel

can someone tell me if there's an easy way to enable mousewheel for controls (in runtime)?
i want to use the wheel for scrolling controls as soon as the mouse is over them.

thx

Answer (score 8):

Karl E Peterson shows how to make any control respond to the mousewheel in this [nice article](http://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2009/08/11/reacting-to-the-mousewheel.aspx) in Visual Studio Magazine, with [VB6 code you can just drop into your project](http://vb.mvps.org/samples/snatch.asp?id=HookXP).

Comment: Source link is now gone... but can be found in way back machine: https://web.archive.org/web/20100109083057/http://www.vb.mvps.org/samples/HookXP/

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at this vbforums example code: [Enabling MouseWheel Support with any control](http://www.vbforums.com/attachment.php?attachmentid=47024)

[Ref](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?t=388222).

Answer (score 0):

One very easy way is to install [VBScroll by Shahin Gasanov](http://www.gasanov.net/VBScroll.asp). This is to enable scroll bars in the VB6 IDE. Even if that's no what you meant by 'the runtime' then it's worth having anyhow ;)

Answer (score 0):

This solution works fine for me. Method 1 http://support.microsoft.com/kb/837910